# Why is this code not being accepted for the SPOJ next Palindrome Problem?

Tags: c++

Here is the question called "The Next Palindrome" from [SPOJ](https://www.spoj.com/problems/PALIN/)

> T test cases are required to be taken first. For a given positive
>   integer K of not more than 1000000 digits, write the value of the
>   smallest palindrome larger than K to output. Numbers are always
>   displayed without leading zeros. If K itself is a palindrome, the
>   output still has to be the next possible palindrome.

I tried passing each number after K as an argument to a function pcheck() which checks if it is a palindrome. Once the next possible palindrome is found, flag 'f' is set to '1' and is returned to main.
Then it prints the number.

So far, this code has worked correctly and found the right answer.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int pcheck(int);

int main()
{
    int t, x, p;
    cin >> t;

    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        cin >> x;
        x = x + 1;

        while (x != 0) {
            p = pcheck(x);

            if (p == 1) {
                cout << x << endl;
                break;
            }
            else {
                x = x + 1;
            }

            p = 0;
        }
    }
}

int pcheck(int t)
{
    int a, m = 0, f = 0;
    int g = t;

    while (t > 0) {
        a = t % 10;
        t = t / 10;
        m = (m * 10) + a;
    }

    if (m == g) {
        f = 1;
    }

    return f;
}
```

The solution is not accepted and is being flagged as "Wrong Answer" on the website.

Comment: What' the largest number you've tested it with?

Comment: 1000000 digits. Think on how big that number is.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], what is SPOJ? what is the input? what is the expected and actual output? Questions should be standalone without reliance on links to external sites

Comment: As @user4581301 point out you have misread a problem. Number have lots of more digits then `int` can hold. Your `x` must be `std::string` so you are able to handle such big number.

Comment: @MarekR has pointed out something which could be the problem here, I'll try what he has suggested.